# breaking one column in two column article

Tags: two-column

I have a page in a two column document that occupies only one column. In the next page I have an image that occupies both columns. The idea is to divide the one column text into two columns and then put the image below. I tried \vfill, \columnbreak, \vfill\null and combinations and nothing works. Although \newpage indeed works by cutting the text column into two, then the image wont go up.
Can you please help? Thanks!
[image]

```
\documentclass{aa}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext

\begin{center}
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image-b} 
\end{figure*}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is a clear question; the only thing is: what is `\documentclass{aa}`? Is it some custom style/class that you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- your question is not very clear. do my suspect, that you have standard two column document and you like to have figure over two columns on the same page where it is insert in text?
- if my guessing s correct, than you can this achieve with package `stfloats`
- off-topic: newer put floats environments inside `\begin{center}...\end{center}` or any other no float environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum*[1]
    \begin{figure*}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{example-image-b}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If this suggestion meets your expectation, then please do accept the answer...